# Reduce the degree and solve the polynomial equation $x^6+ax^4-2x^3+1=0$ by algebraic tricks

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

> Reduce the degree of the polynomial and solve by algebraic tricks: $$x^6+ax^4-2x^3+1=0$$ where $a\in\mathbb R$.

---

$a=0$ is obviously trivial. I tried all possible algebraic variations.

$$\frac {P(x)}{x^n}$$ where $P(x)=x^6+ax^4-2x^3+1$. For example,

$$\frac {P(x)}{x^3}=x^3+ax-2+\frac 1{x^3}=x^3+\frac 1{x^3}+ax-2=0$$

None of these tricks worked, because I couldn't spot the palindromic property. Do you think it would make sense to apply the factorization method?

Comment: @user1094359: Are you only interested in real roots?

Comment: @quasi Only the trick is important

Comment: What do you mean by reduce it's degree? Do you mean to find a polynomial equation of strictly less degree with the same solution set?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose yes. This is obvious. There is no general formula for sextic.

Comment: The only reason factoring out $x^3$ would work is if the polynomial was palindromic. In doing so, you must have $a=\pm 2$ for there to be a simplification. It is most likely impossible to come up with a solution to the sextic without some sort of constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $c\in\mathbb{C}$ be such that $c^2=-a$, we get
\begin{align*}
&\,
x^6+ax^4-2x^3+1
\\[4pt]
=&\,
(x^6-2x^3+1)-c^2x^4
\\[4pt]
=&\,
(x^3-1)^2-(cx^2)^2
\\[4pt]
=&\,
\bigl((x^3-1)+cx^2\bigr)
\bigl((x^3-1)-cx^2\bigr)
\\[4pt]
=&\,
(x^3+cx^2-1)
(x^3-cx^2-1)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so solving the given equation reduces to solving two cubic equations.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer. !

Comment: That is really really elegant. I particularly like the fact that it shows there are no real roots if $a>0$.